# Add rectangle as inline-element with iText

Tags: itext

How do I add a rectangle (or other graphical elements) as inline-elements to an iText PDF?

Example code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
foreach (Row r in entrylist)
{
    p = new Paragraph();
    p.IndentationLeft = 10;
    p.SpacingBefore = 10;
    p.SpacingAfter = 10;

    p.Add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10));  <<<<<<<<< THAT ONE FAILS
    p.Add(new Paragraph(r.GetString("caption"), tahoma12b));
    p.Add(new Paragraph(r.GetString("description"), tahoma12));
    ((Paragraph)p[1]).IndentationLeft = 10;
    doc.Add(p);
}
```

It's something like a column of text-blocks, of which each of them have (only a printed)  checkbox.

I've tried various things with `DirectContent`, but it requires me to provide absolute X and Y values. Which I simply don't have. The elements should be printed at the current position, wherever that may be.

Any clues?

Comment: What do you mean by "THAT ONE FAILS"? It's not displayed? It's displayed but not at the expected position? It throws an exception?

Comment: It actually throws an Exception "Insertion of illegal Element: 30". The type of element is not welcome by the Add method. I do not necessarily need to compile the code above, it's merely to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Chunk` for which you've defined a [*generic tag*](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=206). For instance, in [this example](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_years.pdf) listing a number of movies, a snippet of pellicule is drawn around the year a movie was produced and an ellipse was drawn in the background of the link to IMDB.

If you look at the [MovieYears](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=97) example, you'll find out how to use the `PdfPageEvent` interface and its `onGenericTag()` method. You're right that you can't add a `Rectangle` to a `Paragraph` (IMHO that wouldn't make much sense). As you indicate, you need to draw the rectangle to the direct content, and you get the coordinates of a `Chunk` by using the `setGenericTag()` method. As soon as the `Chunk` is drawn on the page, its coordinates will be passed to the `onGenericTag()` method.

Comment: That works. A bit complicated though. Personally, I would have preferred an abstract object of which I could override the OnDraw Method or so. For instance: `MyRectangle : IPdfDrawable`

Comment: In fact it would make a lot of sense to add graphics to inline text. Look at HTML, it's very simple. I need custom icons (triangles) aligned with the text of a table cell. Seems almost impossible with iText.