# Creating Inline Form Fields with iText

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create a form field inline with text using iText to create the PDF, something that looks like the following:

"Before ☑ after"

I understand that you can use a generic tag event on a Chunk to draw over/under Chunk text (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183507/add-rectangle-as-inline-element-with-itext)) however I do not want any text, and want to specify a specific width/height. I want the form field to flow with the text (e.g. go to newlines when required) so don't want to draw at an absolute position.

I tried to hack a solution by creating a Chunk with the em space character (\u2003) and setting the font point size to whatever I need to get the desired width, and adding the field within the generic tag event. I also tried creating a dummy image of a fixed width and height, so I can add it to the Chunk constructor to get a Chunk of the desired width/height. Obviously neither of these solutions are ideal, I feel like I may be missing something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nope, you're not missing anything obvious. ISO-32000-1 is crystal clear about form fields: AcroForm fields **require** fixed coordinates (as does text). Hence you need to introduce something like an empty `Chunk` to retrieve the coordinates, and you need to use those coordinates to create the field. That's inherent to PDF. It's true in general, not limited to iText.

Comment: Cheers Bruno. If I know for example my field is 30 units wide, and I draw it at the Chunk coordinates, is there a way to "move forward" where the next added Chunk will appear by 30 units (or onto the next line if required)? Sort of like adding a tab chunk of a fixed width, which I can then draw over.